# What's a word for seasonal holiday decorations?

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the word that describes seasonal holiday decorations that people sometimes put up in their offices or desks to mark certain holidays? I feel like I know there is a word for it but I can't remember it however hard I try now. I thought of a pageant - but that is really a procession or ceremony.

Comment: Are you talking about Christmas decorations, but are afraid to use the word?

Comment: In the above case, you may go for ornaments.

Comment: @tchrist Not really. These are decorations that change all year round marking seasons, holidays such as President's day, Memorial day, St. Patrick's Day, Graduation day, Labor day, July 4th, Halloween and of course, Christmas.

Comment: @Playmaker Yes, I thought about that. It's more of a diorama than anything else with many small characters and almost like a nativity scene but specific to various holidays. Diorama? Hmm.

Comment: I would use the word *decoration* or *ornament* for most any holiday. Unless you're thinking of a specific object. These are words for such items in general

Comment: Besides ornaments, baubles, tinsel ... ?

Comment: I am unaware of any single word that describes that.

Comment: "Bunting" isn't quite right, but for what it's worth: "Strips of material used as festive decoration, especially in the colours of the national flag" (http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bunting)

Comment: What's wrong with "holiday decorations"? I think that's the most common and natural phrase.

Comment: @Jay Perhaps because *holiday decorations* isn’t quite the same thing as *holiday décor*.  Just a guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seasonal *trimmings* may suffice for these little flourishes of special, per-season décor elements that some folks decorate their homes with.

Comment: I like **decor**. As a matter of fact, I might like this answer better if you reversed the terms, i.e.: _Seasonal **décor** may suffice for these little flourishes of special, per-season trimmings that some folks decorate with_. (BTW, "seasonal decor" made for a very telling Google images search – a mix of Halloween, Thanksgiving, and Christmas, along with some Easter and patriotic stuff strewn about as well.)

Comment: Thanks everyone for sharing your thoughts! For now seasonal trimmings seems pretty precise! Thank you, @tchrist!

Answer (score 1):

I concur with Lynn about their not being a good single word.

I would consider *bric-a-brac*.

> "Her work area was full of holiday bric-a-brac."

This might convey what you want, but it also might be too general like Zairja's *paraphernalia* suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

In a more general sense, you might use *paraphernalia*.

> Miscellaneous articles, esp. the equipment needed for a particular activity.

However, it's not necessarily a common construct (a Google search of "holiday paraphernalia" returns only 14,300 results).